# Consistent solution of the equation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\xi_n(b, \omega)$ be random variables, $b$ is parameter. It is known that 
$$
\xi_n(b, \omega) \stackrel{P}  \rightarrow \xi(b), \quad n\to \infty,
$$
where $\xi(b)$ is determenistic function. $\xi_n(\cdot, \omega)$ is bounded. $\xi_n(b, \cdot)$ and $\xi(b)$ are differentiable and monotonically increasing with respect to $b.$

Define $\widehat{b}_n(\omega)$ solution of the eqaution $\xi_n(b, \omega)=0$ and $b^{\ast}$ - solution of $\xi(b)=0$ (if they exist).

In what case it is possible to consider that 
$$
\widehat{b}_n(\omega) \stackrel{P}  \rightarrow  b^{\ast}, \quad n\to\infty ?
$$

Can we make any conclusion about $\widehat{b}_n(\omega)$ and $b^{\ast}$ in general?